# Is there a way to prevent rust compiler from rearranging my code?

Tags: performance, rust

After inspecting a disassembly of my binary, I realised that compiler turned

```
expensive_function();
let t1 = Instant::now();
let ptr = get_mut_ptr::<AtomicUsize>();
(ptr).store(some_value, Ordering::Relaxed);
let t2 = Instant::now();
```

into

```
let t1 = Instant::now();
expensive_function();
let ptr = get_mut_ptr::<AtomicUsize>();
(ptr).store(some_value, Ordering::Relaxed);
let t2 = Instant::now();
```

And completely screwed my performance measurements.

Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: Would a memory fence help? https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/41091

Comment: It's hard to say without knowing `expensive_function()`. Perhaps [`std::hint::black_box`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/hint/fn.black_box.html) could help?

Comment: I doubt that'd help as `Instant::now()` is a local value, so even if the compiler is maximally pessimistic about expensive_function it could still decide that reordering `Instant::now` is a good idea. A compiler fence seems like a more reliable solution. Though even then, you'd still be at the mercy of the CPU itself deciding to reorder the operations, because they're independent. This also applies to t2, store, and the "expensive operation".

Comment: `Instant::now()` should register as a volatile operation, so shouldn't be moved around anyways. It would be nice to have an example on [the Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/)

Comment: I tried inserting compiler_fenc(Ordering::SeqCt) with no success.

Comment: Can you confirm whether `expensive_function` has side effects, or whether it is a pure computation with no input arguments?